# Is this a Chinese knockoff (maybe a search engine?) of StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for some css animations, and that's when I found [Manongdao.com website (is this a Chinese site?)](https://www.manongdao.com)

The content of this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985018/simple-css-animation-loop-fading-in-out-loading-text) is present in this [manongdao.com link](https://www.manongdao.com/article-55227.html)!

Infact, it seems almost all of the StackOverflow content is present in this website.

I don't know whether this website is somehow affiliated with StackExchange/StackOverflow. But it seemed a bit off to me, to have all the contents of one website present in another (is this plagiarism?).

Maybe I'm being paranoid here.

[Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=manongdao) & [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=manongdao) seems to have no record of it.

[image]

I asked [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01YTKnjhsEd5KI250RTkar2XeN9wQ%3A1583263861789&ei=dbBeXszbL4j99QOV35XoCQ&q=manongdao+wiki&oq=manongdao+wiki&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2j0i13l8.37244.37405..37640...0.0..0.171.633.0j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i13i30.I59veClu5xE&ved=0ahUKEwiM6sTAhf_nAhWIfn0KHZVvBZ0Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) about it, which resolved into:

[image]